# .Net Maui app - Implement Google Fit or Health Connect?

Tags: android, maui, google-fit, .net-maui

I'm trying to use the old FitnessClass.HistoryApi (obsolete) with GoogleApiClient (obsolete) method but I'm not sure if that will work. I'm having to compile the Android app using net6.0-android as the Target Framework.

Does anyone know if Google Fit will work in a Maui app?

Does anyone know how to implement Health Connect in Maui? I'm interested in the History API.

https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect-guidelines/migrate/migration-guide

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. I had to write this class, though.

```
public class OldScopes : Java.Lang.Object
        {
            [Register("FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ")]
            public const string FitnessActivityRead = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read";

            [Register("FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE")]
            public const string FitnessActivityReadWrite = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.write";

            [Register("FITNESS_LOCATION_READ")]
            public const string FitnessLocationRead = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.read";

            [Register("FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE")]
            public const string FitnessLocationReadWrite = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.write";

            [Register("FITNESS_NUTRITION_READ")]
            public const string FitnessNutritionRead = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.nutrition.read";

            [Register("FITNESS_NUTRITION_READ_WRITE")]
            public const string FitnessNutritionReadWrite = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.nutrition.write";
        }
```